# pytorch deep learning loading data sequentially and efficiently

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I have been doing neural network analysis on 20 thousand "images", each image represented in the form of the intensity of 100 * 100 * 100 neurons.

```
x = np.loadtxt('imgfile')
x = x.reshape(-1, img_channels, 100, 100, 100)
//similarly for target variable 'y'
```

Above, the first dimension of x will be the number of images. Am using DataLoader to get appropriate number of images for training during each iteration as shown below.

```
batch_size = 16
traindataset = TensorDataset(Tensor(x[:-testdatasize]), Tensor(y[:-testdatasize]) )
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=traindataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (data,targets) in enumerate(train_loader):   
        ...
```

I hope to increase the number of images to 50k but am restricted by the computer memory  (imgfile is ~50 GB).

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to handle all the data? Like, rather than loading the whole imgfile, can we first divide them into sets, each with batch_size number of images, and load the sets periodically during training. I am not completely sure how to implement this.

I found some similar ideas using Keras here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/

Please point me towards any similar ideas implemented with pytorch or you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Digging a while after posting the question, found out there is, of course, a way using torch.utils.data.Dataset. Each image-data can be saved in a separate file and all the filenames are listed in 'filelistdata'. Only the batch_size number of images will be loaded into memory when called using DataLoader (in the background, **getitem** method will fetch the images). The following worked for me:

```
traindataset = CustDataset(filename='filelistdata', root_dir=root_dir)

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=traindataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers = 16)
```

num_workers is really important for performance and should be higher than the number of Cpus you are using (I am using 4 cpus above). Found the following resources useful for answering this question.

[How to split and load huge dataset that doesn't fit into memory into pytorch Dataloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836355/how-to-split-and-load-huge-dataset-that-doesnt-fit-into-memory-into-pytorch-dat/57843010#57843010)

[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoZHd0Zm3RY